Graph API SharePoint site file upload: complile error DriveItemRequestBuilder does not contain a definition for Root
I am trying to upload file to a SharePoint Site's shared folder using the following code:
var uploadSession = await _graphClient.Sites[siteId]
   .Drives[driveId]
   .Root
   .ItemWithPath($"{folderPath}{info.Name}")
   .CreateUploadSession()
   .Request()
   .PostAsync();

I got compile error:

'DriveItemRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Root' and no accessible extension method 'Root' accepting a first argument of type 'DriveItemRequestBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've also tried to use .Items["root"] instead of .Root, same error
Further thoughts:

I realized that this is because some breaking changes in Microsoft.Graph nuget package, with version 4.x.x it seems to be compile at least. However I must use the 5.x.x package for other code parts.
To make finding the answer even more hopeless I realized that there are two different DriveItemRequestBuilder class, one in the namespace Microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.DriveItemRequestBuilder this is for the personal folder like var uploadSession = await _graphClient.Drives[myDrive?.Id] and a completely different in Microsoft.Graph.Sites.Item.Drives.Item.DriveItemRequestBuilder this is for _graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drive... this is for the Sites, and what I need.

Literally all examples are either for the legacy version, or the personal folder...

Code for SDK v5 is autogenerated and generating of C# code for some paths like /sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/items/* is restricted.
With a knowledge of driveId, you can directly call /drives/{driveId} to access the root folder and an item by a path
var uploadSession = await _graphClient
.Drives[driveId]
.Root
.ItemWithPath($"{folderPath}{info.Name}")
.CreateUploadSession
.PostAsync(new Microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.CreateUploadSession.CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody { });


Many thx, .... the path contains the siteid, but where is the siteid in the C# builder in your example? This what the difference between the two builder class, for the site builder does not have Root neither Items[]

@g.pickardou If you know driveId, you don't need siteId

many thx for the answer. I try to get the drive id, with no success. The request var site = await _graphClient.Sites[$"{siteUrl}:{sitePath}"].GetAsync(); returns with the site sucessfully, but the site.Drives is null, and if I try directly get the drives then the request  var drives = await _graphClient.Sites[site!.Id].Drives.GetAsync(); is also a success, but there are zero drives in the response. This is a "team site", and there is a folder in it with subfolders with files, which I can browse and see interactively in the site...

In the question you are using driveId, so I expected, it's something you know. await _graphClient.Sites[site!.Id].Drives.GetAsync() works fine for me. Could you check if you have granted permissions Files.Read.All?

I can interactively browse, read, write the files with the same user. I logging in the the web app as the same user

@RaytheonXie-MSFT, The status of my issue can be followed in this very comment section. To be short: 1) The user has full access to the SharePoint Team Site including the created shared folders, 2) The user can successfully get the site data using Graph API in C#, however the issue 3) The requested site data contains zero drives, and also the request directly to get the drives returns zero drives. However without knowing the drive I can not accomplish the original task: upload a file.
I've created a dedicated SO question for this sub issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78558393/1157814

Still seems to me to be an issue with permissions. Could you share what permissions have been granted?

Many thx, it was indeed permissions. Regarding the OP, your answer is definitely working, there is no need for the .Sites[siteId]
