Graph API returns 0 drives for a SharePoint Team Site, on which there is a shared folder and its subfolders with files
Context

I have an Entra ID user "myuser", who can successfully browse list and view folders and files on a SharePoint Team Site called "mysite" using a browser

I have an ASP.NET Core web application (with Azure App Registration), in which the user can log in with his Entra ID user "myuser". The web app successfully acquires access token to the graph api, and successfully can get "mysite" site data including the site id.


Issue

The in response of site data the Drives is null.

If I try send to direct request to get the site's drives, I also get zero drives
  var siteUrl = "<...>.sharepoint.com";
  var sitePath = "/sites/<...>";

  // Get the site ID, 
  // this is success, however site.Drives is null
  var site = await _graphClient.Sites[$"{siteUrl}:{sitePath}"].GetAsync();
  var siteId = site!.Id; // I can get the site id
  // returns HTTP 200, but still with zero drive
  var drives = await _graphClient.Sites[site!.Id].Drives.GetAsync();



My ultimate goal to upload a file to a folder in this Team Site, however first I suppose I must get the drive id, which I can not.
Additional information:
I get the _graphClient in the following way:
"myuser" logs in to the my Web Application using SSO via Microsoft login. The Program.cs I am using:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
  .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
  .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("GraphV1"))

...then I get graphClient via DI in my controllers.

To confirm you want to get the drive ID of the Sharepoint site?

Are you using delegated flow? Did you grant API permissions to the app?

@Rukimi, many thx for you questions. 1) My ultimate goal is to upload a file to the SharePoint Team site, but as far as I know first I must get a driveid.  2) I tried to see the API permissions in the corresponding Azure App Registration, but did not find so much SharePoint related under the Graph API. 3) I am not sure which flow this use case is using so I am adding the corresponding code to the OP now

Did you grant Sites.Read.All delegated API permission? Can you paste the screenshot of it

As the same script works for me for the Team site I am able to get DriveID too

Check this

Many thx, this was the answer, now I got the driveid. I was looking for SharePoint in the search box... . Now trying to progress to the file upload. In case you have time, post a few lines as Answer, I am going to accept it.

Sure posting it as an answer

To fetch the site and drive details you need to grant Sites.Read.All delegated API permission to the Microsoft Entra ID application:

And make use of below code to fetch Site and Drive ID:
        try
        {
            var siteUrl = "Tenant.sharepoint.com:";
            var sitePath = "RukTeamSiteTest";

            var site = await graphClient.Sites[$"{siteUrl}:{sitePath}"].GetAsync();

            Console.WriteLine($"Site ID: {site.Id}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Site Name: {site.Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Site Display Name: {site.DisplayName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Web URL: {site.WebUrl}");

            var drives = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Drives.GetAsync();

            if (drives.Value.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var drive in drives.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Drive ID: {drive.Id}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Drive Name: {drive.Name}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No drives found for this site.");
            }
        }
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}



many thx. you provided a great and fast help again.

Were you able to upload the file to the drive?

thx for asking, finally I managed to work the upload itself too :-)

Glad to know it worked
